# Not possible to register ITypeConverter in AutoFac

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, autofac

I created a WebAPI in .NET Core 2.2. I need use AutoFac and Automapper. I want to write action Create when in DTO one property is convert from int to object.

Converter looks like this:

```cs
public class IntToOfferPlaceConverter : ITypeConverter<int, OfferPlace>
    {
        private readonly IOfferPlaceLogic _logic;

        public IntToOfferPlaceConverter(IOfferPlaceLogic logic)
        {
            _logic = logic;
        }

        public OfferPlace Convert(int source, OfferPlace destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var offerPlaceResult = _logic.GetById(source);
            if (offerPlaceResult.Success == false)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return offerPlaceResult.Value;
        }
    }
```

Prfoile in AutoMapper:

```cs
        public FileProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<FileDto, File>();

            CreateMap<int, OfferPlace>()
                .ConvertUsing<IntToOfferPlaceConverter>();
        }
```

Module in Autofac:

```cs
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ITypeConverter<,>))
                .AsSelf();
        }
```

When mapping occurs, such an error occurs:

```
MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, bool publicOnly, bool wrapExceptions, ref bool canBeCached, ref RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ctor)

AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
FileDto -> File
GrillBer.WebApi.Dto.FileDto -> GrillBer.Models.File

Type Map configuration:
FileDto -> File
GrillBer.WebApi.Dto.FileDto -> GrillBer.Models.File

Destination Member:
OfferPlace
```

The problem lies in the constructor, however, it registers in autofac. Where could I have made a mistake?

Comment: Have you registered `IOfferPlaceLogic` as well? Also as the error states check for default ctors for your DTOs and domain models

Comment: @CristianE. Yes, I register IOffer Place Logic, uses it in several places and everything works well there.

Comment: Then make sure your `File` and `FileDto` have public parameterless constructors. So that Automapper can create an instance of them. If no constructors are present that means the implicit ctor will be used (which is the actual parameterless one) and you should be ok.

Comment: File and FileDto have public pramertless contructor and it still dosen't work.

Comment: This gets simpler if you take Automapper out of the picture. Then take `ITypeConverter` out of the picture. Your code depends on `IOfferPlaceLogic`. The rest both obscures that and makes it harder to test. Since you depend on `IOfferPlaceLogic`, just inject that wherever you need it.

Comment: In fact, it almost looks like you're using Automapper and `ITypeConverter` as a type of repository, as if you're converting an `int` to whatever gets returned from the repository. That adds a layer of confusing on top of simple. If something can be converted, that conversion should always be possible and should always return the same result. A conversion shouldn't depend on whether or not you can retrieve an item with some ID. This is definitely not what Automapper or `ITypeConverter` are for.

Comment: @ScottHannen Unfortunately, it must be so. This converter must return an object from the database. Logic is not a repository but uses it.